# recover variable direct from function in ListView using url pattern Django

Tags: python, html, django

i have a listview

```
class PackageDashboardView(ListView):
      model = Package
      template_name = "packages/dashboard.html"

      def get_queryset(self):
         sort = self.kwargs.get("sort", None)
         default_order_by = "title"
      if sort == 'date':
            default_order_by = "-started"
     queryset = Package.objects.all().
          order_by(default_order_by, 
         'version__name', 
         'seasons').select_related('title', 
         'version').defer('title__metadata', 
         'validation', 'translations', 
         'diff_fields')
    return queryset
```

url.py

```
url(r'^packages/sort:(?P<sort>\w+)$', packages.PackageDashboardView.as_view(), name="package_dashboard"),
```

template.html

```
<a href="/packages/sort:date"><div class="controller type">by Date</div></a>
<a href="/packages/sort:title"><div class="controller type">by Title</div></a>
```

i want to pass variable sort direct in my function get_queryset without passing with self.kwargs.get("sort", None)

Comment: Well the variables are not passed as arguments, as one can see when following the `get(..)` function, so except for unpacking the variables somewhere else (and thus "moving" the work to another function), there are not much options. https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/

Comment: your "sort" argument should be part of the querystring (ie "/packages/?sort=date"), not part of the url (it's the same resource, not a different one). Also you should really use the `{% url %}` templatetag instead of hardcoding urls in your templates.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers can i do a function where i pass sort param directly to parametres of this function without passing with kwargs.get

Comment: Yes, if you insist on making it part of the url (which, I repeat,  is a bad idea since it's NOT a different resource), just use a function-based view and setup your url pattern correctly. But really I don't see the point.